# Pattern for User input processing

Tags: java, console-application, design-patterns

I need to do some basic Java console application with menus and submenus. The structure should look something like this:

Main menu:

```
(1)     Menu 1
(2)     Menu 2
(0)     Exit  

Menu 1 
(1)  Submenu 1 
(2)  Submenu 2 
(3)  Submenu 3 
(4)  Return to menu 1
```

So, when user enters 1, Menu 1 will be printed, etc...

My question is, can I achieve this kind of thing with some pattern, and create more dynamic approach, or am I stuck with if switch statements ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Menus are pretty easy to implement using while loops and switch statements.

Comment: Ok, i thought there is a "way around", so I can create more dynamic stuff if needed in future. But thanks anyway.

Comment: the user-input could be the index of a Runnable[] array with the implementations of the tasks. But writing a class for each task would be inappropriate for a small application with a small menu.

Comment: With an interface Menu { int size(); String getMenuItemLabel(int index); void run(int index); } the 'gui' would be dynamic and it would use a for. But the Menu.run() implementation would still do it with if/switch/Runnable[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using switch statements, you could create an object which contains an array of strings for the submenus, and an array of submenu objects numbered corresponding to their keypress value. For this you can use a method like this to return the submenu:

```
menu getSubmenu(int keyval){
    return menulist[keyval];
}
```

I'll leave the rest of the implementation up to you.